# Importing notes to accounts in dynamics CRM

Tags: import, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am trying to upload notes that we have stored in our database and link them to accounts that we have uploaded to CRM. We have Imported Accounts and Contacts Successfully using the import templates provided in the CRM data management already.

The template Note import file comes in this format
[image: Notes Template]

According to online forums, to get a note linked against an account, an extra column called "Regarding" Needs to be added and populated with the exact match of the account name that it is to be linked to. Like this:

[image]

When we have tried to use this format, the import is successful and we can see the notes:

[image]

But when looking at the notes that are imported, the regarding field is not populated and it is grayed out and not able to be clicked.

[image]

Does anyone know what i can do about this issue?

Cheers in advance

EDIT:

I do not have any options during import to edit the fields being mapped or anything like that. The most control i have is setting the owner of the import.

Step 1: Choose File
[image]

Step 2: Change owner and duplicates options and submit
[image]

EDIT 2:
To get templates i go Settings > Data Management > Templates > select Note from drop-down, i have put screenshots of the process below.

Go to Data Management:
[image]

Click on Templates:
[image]

Select Notes and download (note this downloads as an .xlsx file):
[image]

With the template, here is how it downloads, and then i add the regarding column on before i upload and populate it with the account names that it is regarding:
[image]

Comment: Are you mapping the Regarding column when importing?

Comment: I cannot find a way to do that. How do i map? i have tried looking at creating data maps but i can only see an option to import an XML file in to create one. I can't seem to find the nice GUI with mapping options that are posted on online forums.

Comment: When you are importing the data you have the "Edit" option, after that check if regarding field is getting mapped and you are looking for the right entity (Accounts).

Comment: Hey Sxntk, i cannot see any edit option. i have edited the post to give screen shots of what i can see when importing.

Comment: In the Step 2, if you go back, you can see the edit option? If you can't rename the regarding colunm (Name it "Regar") and try to import again

Comment: hitting the back button in step 2 doesn't give any more options that what was in the step 1 screenshot. Have tried renaming the excel column to Regar and still no luck

Comment: Go to Settings, Data Administration, Download the Note Template (It should be an .xml not an .xlsx) and copy the data to that template, if there isn't enough fields fill more columns and try again.

Comment: Have gone back to template download, it does not give me the option to choose xml. i have edited the question to show the process of getting the template. Thank you for taking the time to help me with this. I appreciate all your help

Comment: Maybe with a .csv we can map the fields, Try this way and import it again. [Refer to Step 1 and 2](http://gotcrm.blogspot.com.co/2013/05/crm-2011-migrating-notes-while.html)

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you. That was it. saving the excel file as CSV allowed me to the have the option of mapping. Please write that as an answer and i will mark it as accepted :) Thank you again

Comment: Your welcome, hope the answer help other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default template for importing notes doesn't allow you to map fields, even the template for export and import the records doesn't show the Regarding field.

To map fields you need to save as the import file as .csv, then when you are importing the data to crm in the second step select to edit the mapping, map the regarding field to the column you defined and import the data.